# unable to connect on localhost:3000 from browser

Tags: reactjs, docker, tcp, localhost

I created a docker app to run a react application to run on localhost port 3000. Suddenly I am seeing that it is not running; what I have seen in Netstat is that it is time-wait.

This is the output I got after running `netstat -plant`:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 172.18.0.1:5025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp        0      0 172.16.100.1:5025       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp        0      0 192.168.233.1:5025      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:5025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:5025      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5025          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37925           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1924/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:902             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8526/vmware-authdla 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3302/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1909/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36678/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2758/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      39955/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3302/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7070            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2333/anydesk        
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:59416     151.101.193.69:443      ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp       78      0 192.168.31.46:43086     34.215.76.123:443       CLOSE_WAIT  33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:37940     157.240.15.17:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:40770     142.250.195.66:443      ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55552         127.0.0.1:8080          ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:38084     157.240.15.17:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:48400     142.250.196.164:443     ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:40690     52.111.252.2:443        ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      1 172.18.0.1:48992        172.18.0.2:3000         SYN_SENT    39955/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:44748     52.111.252.0:443        ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:37930     157.240.15.17:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          127.0.0.1:47782         ESTABLISHED 39955/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47782         127.0.0.1:3000          ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:48900     110.76.130.81:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:60481     52.163.231.110:443      ESTABLISHED 32695/skypeforlinux 
tcp        1      0 192.168.31.46:50192     107.167.110.223:443     CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:45422     20.185.212.106:443      ESTABLISHED 32684/skypeforlinux 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:39872     142.251.10.188:443      ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:45756     142.250.182.38:443      ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp       25      0 192.168.31.46:60728     103.83.123.88:443       CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:60486     13.33.28.118:443        ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:55874     216.58.196.162:443      ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:36654     104.18.99.194:443       ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:49272     157.240.15.1:443        ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:60730     103.83.123.88:443       CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        1      0 192.168.31.46:45328     104.18.11.39:80         CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:37192     110.76.130.136:443      ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:59506     13.107.6.171:443        ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          127.0.0.1:47772         ESTABLISHED 39955/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:52622     13.76.217.211:443       ESTABLISHED 32684/skypeforlinux 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:59386     13.107.6.171:443        ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:33478     103.229.10.173:443      ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47772         127.0.0.1:3000          ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      1 172.18.0.1:48984        172.18.0.2:3000         SYN_SENT    39955/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47770         127.0.0.1:3000          ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:38176     157.240.15.17:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:55340     199.232.253.140:443     ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp       32      0 192.168.31.46:52344     18.205.51.212:443       CLOSE_WAIT  33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:40662     52.111.252.2:443        ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp      674      0 127.0.0.1:3000          127.0.0.1:47770         ESTABLISHED 39955/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          127.0.0.1:55552         ESTABLISHED 36678/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:51660     151.101.129.69:443      ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:45420     20.185.212.106:443      ESTABLISHED 32684/skypeforlinux 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:60732     103.83.123.88:443       CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.1:50214        172.17.0.3:80           ESTABLISHED 36678/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:37482     107.167.110.216:443     CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:47592     13.227.214.108:443      ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:46436     108.174.11.37:443       ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:44592     142.250.182.130:443     ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:52876     74.125.68.188:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:55978     151.101.129.140:443     ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:42314     142.250.76.72:443       ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp       25      0 192.168.31.46:50150     107.167.110.223:443     CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:55478     75.2.53.94:443          ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp       25      0 192.168.31.46:37490     107.167.110.216:443     CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:46432     108.174.11.37:443       ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp       25      0 192.168.31.46:52600     185.26.182.118:443      CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:60420     192.229.232.200:443     ESTABLISHED 32684/skypeforlinux 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:34998     140.82.112.25:443       ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:50030     52.109.124.33:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:48532     13.107.21.200:443       ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:46420     108.174.11.37:443       ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp       25      0 192.168.31.46:60734     103.83.123.88:443       CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      1 172.18.0.1:48982        172.18.0.2:3000         SYN_SENT    39955/docker-proxy  
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:33593     46.4.60.45:80           ESTABLISHED 2333/anydesk        
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:33932     142.250.193.163:443     ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:59020     198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp       25      0 192.168.31.46:41286     107.167.110.211:443     CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:42886     151.101.36.193:443      ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        1      0 192.168.31.46:37442     13.67.9.5:443           CLOSE_WAIT  40378/code --type=u 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:38106     157.240.15.17:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:58954     198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:53582     151.101.1.2:443         ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:39822     52.111.240.2:443        ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        1      0 192.168.31.46:52360     18.205.51.212:443       CLOSE_WAIT  33791/chrome --type 
tcp       25      0 192.168.31.46:34720     185.26.182.123:443      CLOSE_WAIT  41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:50378     151.101.1.26:443        ESTABLISHED 33791/chrome --type 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:38088     157.240.15.17:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      0 192.168.31.46:50008     52.109.124.33:443       ESTABLISHED 41671/opera --type= 
tcp        0      1 172.17.0.1:50114        172.17.0.3:80           LAST_ACK    -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::49631                :::*                    LISTEN      1924/rpc.statd      
tcp6       0      0 fe80::109a:16ff:fe:5025 :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::88ab:42ff:fe:5025 :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::42:5ff:fe96::5025 :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::f76b:88d5:d4:5025 :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::9472:48ff:fe:5025 :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::250:56ff:fec:5025 :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::250:56ff:fec:5025 :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::42:46ff:fe1a:5025 :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5025                :::*                    LISTEN      32384/qbittorrent   
tcp6       0      0 :::902                  :::*                    LISTEN      8526/vmware-authdla 
tcp6       0      0 :::6566                 :::*                    LISTEN      2759/saned          
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2453/docker-registr 
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      3302/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1909/rpcbind        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      2758/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      3302/smbd           
tcp6       1      0 ::1:58816               ::1:631                 CLOSE_WAIT  2752/cups-browsed   
tcp6       1      0 ::1:58814               ::1:631                 CLOSE_WAIT  2752/cups-browsed
```

It can be seen that the docker proxy connection has been established on port 3000. But the browser cannot access it. What can be the reasons behind this issue?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], or any instructions on how to reproduce the issue?  It's hard to infer anything from just the `netstat` output.